# car with steering control urdf model: teb_local_planner

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I need to design a car model with the steering control. For this , several of the packages are available out of which the [teb_local_planner(car like model)](http://wiki.ros.org/teb_local_planner/Tutorials/Planning%20for%20car-like%20robots) seems to be very suitable.
But , i am unable to find any urdf model of the car like robot in the package files (as shown in the video of the car like robot). Does that mean we need to use our own car like model?

UPDATE:
I need to design a car like robot model with the steering control.
The first doubt of mine is that , the launch file of the "teb_local_planner" does not include any urdf model, then how is the teb_local_planner working? and if i need to use my robot model, then what all changes are to be required?

Also, I have seen the use of exporter plug-in of the solid-work which will help to get the urdf model of the 3D Model.
Can i get the car with steering model with this plug in of solid work? (as there are many 3D Models available for the car in solid-work community).

And if it is not possible to extract the urdf of a steering machine, then which tutorial or source should i follow for this?

Kindly help in this regard.

Thank you.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/258774/car-with-steering-control-urdf-model:-teb_local_planner/) by [Ayush Sharma](https://answers.ros.org/users/28428/ayush-sharma/) on ROS Answers with karma: 41 on 2017-04-07

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [zeal](https://answers.ros.org/users/29860/zeal/) on 2017-04-14**:
As i know , we use teb_local_planner for 2d_navigation，so there only exists a footprint configuration in teb，you can define the car's footprint and min_turing_radius in the yaml file。you can see the  tutorials : http://wiki.ros.org/teb_local_planner/Tutorials/Planning%20for%20car-like%20robots

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

My approach to simulate a car like robot was to develop a SDF model because it has a revolute2 joint that allow the wheels to rotate around two different axis simultaneous. In my case URDF is made just for RVIZ visualization and to define the transformations between robot's frames. Hope it helps. Any doubt feel free to ask

---

Originally posted by [agbj](https://answers.ros.org/users/29369/agbj/) with karma: 83 on 2017-04-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0